# Automatic initialization of backing fields

Tags: c#, initialization

This question is **not** about how to initialize backing fields...

Lets say given this class:

```
public class Test
{
    public int PropertyA { get; set; }
    public int PropertyB { get; set; }
    private int _propertyC;
    public int PropertyC { get { return _propertyC; } set { _propertyC = value; } }
}
```

There are a number of properties defined, both automatically and explicitly implemented.

Lets take a closer look at how `PropertyA` gets compiled (64-bit debug). The MSIL output is this:

```
.field private int32 'k__BackingField'
.custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
.custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggerBrowsableAttribute::.ctor(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggerBrowsableState) = ( 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 )

.property instance int32 PropertyA()
{
  .get instance int32 TestCode.Test::get_PropertyA()
  .set instance void TestCode.Test::set_PropertyA(int32)
} // end of property Test::PropertyA

.method public hidebysig specialname instance int32 
        get_PropertyA() cil managed
{
  .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
  // Code size       7 (0x7)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  ldfld      int32 TestCode.Test::'k__BackingField'
  IL_0006:  ret
} // end of method Test::get_PropertyA

.method public hidebysig specialname instance void 
        set_PropertyA(int32 'value') cil managed
{
  .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
  // Code size       8 (0x8)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  ldarg.1
  IL_0002:  stfld      int32 TestCode.Test::'k__BackingField'
  IL_0007:  ret
} // end of method Test::set_PropertyA
```

Which is pretty basic, it defines the backing field, the property and then the `get_` and `_set` methods for that property that load or set the backing field.

What I don't get (and I've taken for granted up until now), is that this is a perfectly legal constructor:

```
public Test()
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"{PropertyA.ToString()}");
    Debug.WriteLine($"{_propertyC.ToString()}");
}
```

While this is obviously a compiler error:

```
public Test()
{
    int i;
    Debug.WriteLine($"{i.ToString()}");
}
```

Which, as expected, gives CS0165 "Use of unassigned local variable 'i'". In doing some research for this and digging through the [ECMA Spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf), and the [Microsoft C# spec](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029) (5.0 is the last formal document, 6.0 seems to be loosely distributed in the Roslyn project) and I can't find anything related to the initialization of fields.

I did find [this reference from VS2003](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645756(v=vs.71).aspx) that eludes to class fields being initialized to the `default` value for the type, but it suggests that this is part of the language and not the runtime.

So the question is... Does the runtime perform the initialization of the fields, or am I missing something in the MSIL from the compiler that is initializing these values? I'm assuming the compiler does this otherwise I would expect the same CS0165 in both the example constructors.

Comment: So you basically want to understand why you're allowed to invoke an unassigned property but not an unassigned local variable?

Comment: I understand *why* but I don't understand *how*. Where is the initialization happening?

Comment: Isn't this described in §17.4.4 of specification? "The initial value of a field, whether it be a static field or an instance field,  is the default value (§12.2) of the field’s type. It is not possible to observe the value of a field before this default initialization has occurred, and a field is thus never “uninitialized”"? If it's not in the MSIL, I would assume the runtime takes care of it. The compiler just needs to know the rules, i.e. that the specification says it will be initialized, so no warning. Nothing more nothing less.

Comment: The part about definite assignment is covered in part 5.3 of the specification. The initialization will be done by the runtime.

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt Thanks for finding it in the spec (moved quite a bit from 2003), but I do understand why, I'm just wondering where the initialization is implemented.

Comment: @RonBeyer: Well, I used your link to the spec, and simply searched for "initialization"...

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov If you wouldn't mind posting that as an answer that is the section I missed while looking for the field initializers.

Comment: `PropertyA` and `_propertyC` are already initialized when you create an instance of `Test` (which you need to be able to call method `Test()`).

Comment: @Sinatr I understand that, I was wondering *where* the initialization occurs, in the compiler or the runtime, and where it outlines it in the spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the runtime perform the initialization of the fields, or am I missing something in the MSIL from the compiler that is initializing these values?

Part §5.2 and §5.3 of the specification talk about default values and definite assignment, respectively.

A quote from the spec (§5.2):

> Initialization to default values is typically done by having the memory manager or garbage collector initialize memory to all-bits-zero before it is allocated for use. For this reason, it is convenient to use all-bits-zero to represent the null reference.

This goes on to show the memory manager and GC take care of default value initialization.